# Unable to boot to Partition in 12.10

Tags: 12.10

I installed ubuntu 12.10 on asus A55a alongside prexisting windows 7 no boot option for ubuntu.

Laptop boots directly to windows every time and cannot see or use ubuntu partition.

Comment: when you press f8 or f11 during boot logo , which loader do you see ? windows or linux ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same notebook.

I first installed Ubuntu, erasing windows 7. Later installed the Windows on a Partition created by ubuntu.

To access the ubuntu, I have to press ESC when the notebook is starting and choose Ubuntu Partition.

Answer (score 0):

Try going into the system bios to change the one you want to boot to. If you don't want to have to do this every time you want to switch or your system bios won't let you try installing grub boot loader again from a live cd.

More info
http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub.html